# disable animation css file for mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added animation class using jquery to a div.  I have added `animation.css` file in my web page.  I have the class `animated slideInLeft`.  I want to disable the class for mobile device.  Is it possible to display the animation function?

Comment: Use media queries in your animation css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```css
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .animated {
    animation: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries or make a condition on the size of the screen of your device